# jQuery datatable not populating

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables

I have a jQuery data table, getting data through web service API. I can see the data returned is in correct format but the table is not displaying the data.

I have a "Submit" button that on click fetches the data and redraws the table. I put a breakpoint in "success" function and can see the json data.

Javascript on top of the aspx page and data table definition (I needed this js functions because the Search text box on top the datatable kept disappearing on page reloads)

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        bindDataTable(); // bind data table on first page load
        // bind data table on every UpdatePanel refresh
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(bindDataTable);
    });

    function bindDataTable() {
        var FacCertDT = $('#tblFacCert').DataTable({
            'bDestroy': true,
            "bStateSave": true,
            dom: 'lfrtip',
            "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) {
                localStorage.setItem('tblFacCert', JSON.stringify(oData));
            },
            "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) {
                return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tblFacCert'));
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<div runat="server" id="divFacCert" ClientIDMode="Static" style="padding:15px">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="tblFacCert" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr class="info">
                    <th>Area</th>
                    <th>District</th>
                    <th>MPOO </th>
                    <th>Facility</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Sub-Type</th>
                    <th>Response Due Date</th>
                    <th>Completed?</th>
                    <th>Completed By</th>
                    <th>Completed On</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript at the bottom of the page:

```
<script>
    Table = $("#tblFacCert").DataTable({
        data: [],
        "aoColumns": [
            {
                "mData": "Area"
            }, {
                "mData": "District"
            }, {
                "mData": "MPOO"
            }, {
                "mData": "FacilityName"
            }, {
                "mData": "FacilityType"
            }, {
                "mData": "FacilitySubType"
            }, {
                "mData": "ResponseDueDate"
            }, {
                "mData": "Completed"
            }, {
                "mData": "UserName"
            }, {
                "mData": "ResponseDate"
            }
        ],
        "pageLength": 15,
        "deferRender": true,
        rowCallback: function (row, data) { },
        filter: false,
        info: false,
        ordering: false,
        processing: true,
        retrieve: true
    });

    $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "../services/easg.asmx/GetComplianceReportData",
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{ 'startDate': '" + $("#tbStartDate").val() + "', 'certID': '" + $('#ddlCertificate').val() + "'}"
        }).done(function (result) {debugger
            Table.clear().draw();
            Table.rows.add(result).draw();
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
        });
    })
</script>
```

This is what the web service API looks like:

```
namespace FacCert
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for easg
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class easg : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

        public string GetComplianceReportData(string startDate, string certID)
        {
            DateTime dtStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(startDate);
            int iCertItemID = int.Parse(certID);
            DataTable dt = FacCompliance.GetFacCompliances(dtStartDate, iCertItemID);
            string JSONresult;
            JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
            return JSONresult;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the data when I examine it in "on("click")":

```
[
    {
        "Area":"CAPITAL METRO (K)",
        "District":"NORTHERN VIRGINIA",
        "MPOO":"Plant",
        "FacilityName":"DULLES VA P&DC",
        "FacilityType":"Network Operations",
        "FacilitySubType":"P&DC",
        "ResponseDueDate":"2017-12-20T00:00:00",
        "ResponseDate":"2017-12-30T17:57:35.353",
        "UserACEID":"XXXXXX",
        "UserName":"John Doe",
        "Completed":"Yes",
        "AreaID":11,
        "DistrictID":58,
        "FacID":2261,
        "FacComplianceID":1
    },{
        "Area":"CAPITAL METRO (K)",
        "District":"NORTHERN VIRGINIA",
        "MPOO":"Plant",
        "FacilityName":"NORTHERN VA P&DC",
        "FacilityType":"Network Operations",
        "FacilitySubType":"P&DC",
        "ResponseDueDate":"2017-12-20T00:00:00",
        "ResponseDate":"2017-12-30T18:23:10.86",
        "UserACEID":"XXXXXX",
        "UserName":"John Doe",
        "Completed":"Yes",
        "AreaID":11,
        "DistrictID":58,
        "FacID":2262,
        "FacComplianceID":4
    }
]
```

I have searched and tried all suggestions but nothing seems to fix the problem. I am hoping someone here can see where I am messing up.

There are a few columns returned by API that I am not including in the data table (e.g. AreaID, DistrictID, ...).

**update:**

if I replace the variable "result" in Table.rows.add(result).draw(); with actual json array that I have listed in the post, then it displays the data. I got the json data by putting a breakpoint and examining the value of "result", so i am not sure why it works when I use the actual json data and not when I pass it "result".

Comment: can you add sample string of the data returned by your `ajax` call , plus you should return data in `json` format see [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/34175/dynamic-json-populate-to-datatable-on-the-fly)

Comment: I have updated the question and added the data returned and web service API.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with the code or the data, it works right away -> **http://jsfiddle.net/00t2m3bx/** so your problem lies elsewhere ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line in your Ajax `done` method:

```
Table.rows.add(JSON.parse(result.d)).draw();
```

**Edit**
If you are using update panel you can bind your js method with that then your change reflect. put you your button submit code in functuon and set your method name as parameter. i hope it's work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(YourMethod);
    </script>
```

Comment: Could it be because FacilityName contains '&' character?

Comment: No, the ampersand `&` character is valid inside the string values. I tested the data that you posted and it worked with this answer.

Comment: Wrong suggestion since the result already is in JSON format. This is ensured by `dataType: "json"` ...Thats why `JSON.parse()` throws "invalid character" error, it get a literal - not a string as it should...

Comment: OK, at least I know the table and data set up is correct. Data table is in an update panel; would that make any difference? Any suggestion where I should be looking at? This is my first jQuery data table.

Comment: I had missed adding a couple of js function that was on the page to fix an issue with disappearing "Search" text box on page reload. I am including it for completeness and in case ...

Comment: Hafiz, how would I put the submit button code in a function and use it as parameter to add_endRequest? Nothing else seems to work right now so I'd like to try this sugesstion.

Comment: Hafiz was partially right in his answer. I had to add JSON.parse but the parameter  passed to it would not be "result" but "result.d". If you make your comment as answer with correct parameter I will mark it as answer.

Comment: @NoBullMan Done it

Answer (score 0):

After much time spent on this I figured out what the issue was. When I passed the actual json data to Table.rows.add() data was displayed. So I knew there was something wrong with the "result" parameter I was passing. When I looked at the reponse that was returned in Chrome, I noticed it was adding XML tags to it:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
[
    {
        "Area":"CAPITAL METRO (K)",
        "District":"NORTHERN VIRGINIA",
        ....
    }
]
</string>
```

That's why the raw data would display but not when I passed "result" parameter to it.

The fix was to change the button click function like this:

```
$("#btnSubmit").on("click", function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "../services/easg.asmx/GetComplianceReportData",
        cache: false,
        data: "{ 'startDate': '" + $("#tbStartDate").val() + "', 'certID': '" + $('#ddlCertificate').val() + "'}"
    }).done(function (result) {
        Table.clear().draw();
        jResult = JSON.parse(result.d); <--- This is the fix
        Table.rows.add(jResult).draw();
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
    });
})
```