# jQuery datatale using Repeater to populate

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables, repeater

I am trying to set up my first jQuery datatable and running into some issues. Initially, I tried to use web service API and ajax to populate the table and ran into an issue where json data was returned correctly but table was not populating. I opened an SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120180/jquery-datatable-not-populating) for this but still not getting to work.

So, I decided while waiting for a solution to this issue to try another approcah and use a Repeater to populate the table. This approach works fine but for one issue: when data returned contains around 2000 rows and 10 columns, it takes IE (which unfortunately is the default browser at our organization) about one minute to display (way too long) while in Chrome and FF it takes about 3 seconds.

Does anyone know why this happens and if there is a fix or workaround for it? I have searched for this topic but have not found any solution.

Page is using master page and data table is inside an update panel.

Need this script to prevent "Search" textbox and column sorting from disappearing on page reload:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        bindDataTable(); // bind data table on first page load
        // bind data table on every UpdatePanel refresh
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(bindDataTable);
    });

    function bindDataTable() {
        var adminUsersDT = $('#tblFacCert').DataTable({
            'bDestroy': true,
            "bStateSave": true,
            dom: 'lfrtip',
            "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) {
                localStorage.setItem('tblFacCert', JSON.stringify(oData));
            },
            "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) {
                return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tblFacCert'));
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

.aspx:

```
<div runat="server" id="divFacCert" ClientIDMode="Static" style="padding:15px">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptFacCert">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="tblFacCert" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <th>Area</th>
                            <th>District</th>
                            <th>MPOO </th>
                            <th>Facility</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Sub-Type</th>
                            <th>Response Due Date</th>
                            <th>Completed?</th>
                            <th>Completed By</th>
                            <th>Completed On</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </FooterTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                    <td><%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Area"] %></td>
                    <td><%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["District"] %></td>
                    <td><%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["MPOO"] %></td>
                    <td><%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["FacilityName"] %></td>
                    <td><%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["FacilityType"] %></td>
                    <td><%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["FacilitySubType"] %></td>
                    <td><%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["ResponseDueDate"] %></td>
                    <td><%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Completed"] %></td>
                    <td><%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["UserName"] %></td>
                    <td><%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["ResponseDate"] %></td>
                    </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Code behind:

```
private void PopulateTable()
{
    dtCompliance = GetTableData();
    rptFacCert.DataSource = dtCompliance;
    rptFacCert.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Anyone? Down to last few strands of hair!